# I want to prevent other users to access images directly in my Yii application.

Tags: php, security, .htaccess, yii

I have this user directory that contains all my user's profile pictures.
When I use the image tag, it points to that user directory. If someone
wants to access that image using the direct link, they can. I want to
prevent them from being able to access an image directly. Can I use the
asset Manager in yii to make that happen or what I need is a totally 
different thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it and even allow visitors with no HTPP_REFERER:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourotherdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^path/to/user/(.+)?(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|tiff)$ http://yourdomain.com/do_not_hot_link.png [NC, R, L]
```

Just replace yourdomain.com with your domain and the last url with the "forbidden" page (requests are getting redirect to this!)

Comment: So you mean my web app can access the images but when users want to access it directly through a link they get redirected ?

Comment: Also for testing this, since I'm testing on localhost, what should I put instead of domain ?

Comment: 1st: all correct. 2nd: "localhost" or whatever is in your adress bar (e.g. "testing.dev")

Comment: this line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$` allows users to open it in a browser with direct link

Comment: Yeah, but I think he want' s to prevent hot-linking and hotlinking isn' t possible with this. Without this line users behind some kind of proxy server or with browser, which are not sending the referer wouldn' t be able to see the image anywhere... Alex has to decide if he can ignore this problem or wants to make sure, that users cam enjoy his app even under some unusal conditions... But you' re right :)

Comment: Yes Guys. I understand what you are explaining. I'm wondering how Facebook and other social networking websites manage to control this by showing the images to the user but not letting them to randomly browse the user image directory and see other people's profile photo without permission. I am trying to think of a way, maybe creating a controller that takes an image name and return a url for it which is a symbolic link that doesn't expose the actual location, or even if it does, it doesn't allow direct access.

Comment: Ok then you have to serve the image with php by setting headers and only displaying data with the right "permissions". This way you can store the images out side of the web root or on any other host and get the contents of file and echo them out with php (do not forget to set the right header!)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to implement it. And not sure if there is some build in functionality for that in Yii.

There are some easy ways to do it in .htaccess file.

The first approach checks HTTP_REFERER and if it does not much your domain shows 403 Forbidden page:

```
RewriteEngine  on   

RewriteBase  /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !your_domain
RewriteRule ^images - [F,L]
```

where `your_domain` is actually your domain name,
and `images` is the user profile image folder.

There are some downsides in this like in HTTP_REFERER may not be sent by some clients or cut by proxy servers or firewalls.

Another way is to set some cookie in your app and then check it in .htaccess:

```
setcookie("show_img", 1, time()+3600, "/");
```

and then

```
RewriteEngine  on   

RewriteBase  /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !show_img=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^images - [F,L]
```

this approach actually does not prevent your visitors from viewing it using direct link. But it will definitely bring a lot of headache to webmasters who would like to insert images from your server.